# SGE output and notification to the mail

Tags: scripting, gridengine

in a SGE script with

```
#$ -M my_mail@gmail.com 
#$ -m aes
```

SGE send notify of job complete.
how I can receive the output of the job with the this notification ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default GridEngine will not send the job output via email.

The only way I can think of to achieve this is to write a custom epilogue script that runs after a job and emails the output to the user.